# "Я извиняюсь" - как правильно сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Я извиняюсь" -  правильно так говорить?

Answer (score 11):

Если вы обращаетесь к тому, перед кем хотите извиниться, то лучше сказать "Извините" или "Прошу прощения". 
Но это скорее этикетная рекомендация, не грамматическая. В остальных случаях конструкция "Я извиняюсь" вполне возможна: "Я извинился за свою неловкость".

Comment: Вот и получается, что когда я говорю "извините, пожалуйста", то я извиняюсь перед каким-либо человеком за какую-либо неловкость или ошибку. А "я извиняюсь" несет лишь смысловую нагрузку констатации факта, как, например, "я встречаюсь", "я кусаюсь", "я пугаюсь" и пр. Короче, +1.

Comment: @behemothus В Вашем ответе: _Я извинился за свою неловкость._ Думаю, что Вы хотели сказать так: _**Я извиняюсь** за свою неловкость._ Или нет?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова  - Да нет, наверное. Сейчас уж и наверняка не вспомнишь, что я хотел сказать семь лет назад. Но то, как написано, не візівает у меня чувства ошибки. Тут нет причин противопоставлять прошедшее время настоящему. А віглядит более убедительно.

Answer (score 5):

По поводу грамматики. Говорить так можно, правда, к глаголу этому стоит помета "разг." и употреблять это слово отдельно от других та же Грамота.ру не рекомендует. http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti/36_89

Если смотреть с точки зрения этики... Ко мне неожиданно пришли гости, а дома беспорядок. Я извиняюсь, что у меня не убрано, но прощать или извинять себя за это не прошу, так как вины в этом моей нет, что не отменяет того факта, что мне неудобно. Точно также я извиняюсь, если на меня налетит какой-нибудь зазевавшийся человек, так как я хоть и не трамвай и мог его заметить раньше, но и этот человек тоже глаза имеет.
В общем, по-моему, это вполне приемлемая форма извинения за событие, в котором ты своей вины перед извиняющим не ощущаешь, но чувство дискомфорта из-за происшествия всё же испытываешь. В остальных случаях лучше "извините", "простите", "виноват".

*Такой-сякой! Ну что ж, я извиняюсь,*

*Но в глубине ничуть не изменяюсь...*

```
  (О. Мандельштам.)
```

Comment: Личное мнение непонятно кого. 
  
Про словари - вообще ерунда.  
БТС Кузнецова:  
  
ИЗВИНЯЮСЬ см. ИЗВИНИТЬСЯ  
  
ИЗВИНИТЬСЯ, -нюсь, -нишься; св.  
1.
Попросить извинения, прощения. И. за долгое молчание. И. за сына, за друга, перед другом. Толкнул и не извинился. Официально и. за что-л. Должен и. перед вами за свои слова.
2. чем. Устар.
Привести что-л. в качестве смягчающего вину обстоятельства, в качестве оправдания. < Извиняться, -яюсь, -яешься; извиняющийся; нсв. Извиняюсь, в зн. межд. Разг. (обычно в вопросе).
Вежливая форма обращения к кому-л. И., это не ваш сын? И., я опоздал.

Comment: Личное мнение тут моё, о чём прямо написано во втором абзаце. Мнение словарей приведено в первом. А словари, как раз дают помету "разг" как у Ожегова и процитированного вами Кузнецова, или "прост" как у Ушакова.

Comment: Всегда я считал слово "извиняюсь"(в смысле просьбы: "извините меня") ошибочным, тождественным выражению: "извиняю себя", что явно не вяжется со здравым смыслом. Но после приведенных примеров из литературы и разговорной речи, которые почему-то не улеглись в моей памяти, я стал сомневаться в собственном убеждении, хотя "извиняюсь" - в начале текста - конечно, правильно я считал ошибочным. И всё-таки раздвоенность моя пойдёт мне, чувствую, не на пользу. Язык - не математика: этим он и хорош, и плох. Но мне уже почти всё равно. А как быть школьникам? "Как стать грамотным?"

Answer (score 3):

Вот что сообщает нам по этому поводу «Словарь русского речевого этикета». Если «извините» – это широкоупотребительная форма вежливого извинения, то «извиняюсь» – это просторечное слово, которое, извините, находится вообще за рамками литературной нормы. Считается, что это самое «извиняюсь» вошло в оборот со времен первой мировой войны, с 1914 года.

«Кому не известна формула большевистской вежливости – “извиняюсь”? – писал не без горечи знаменитый русский языковед Селищев о языке революционной эпохи. – Сколько прекрасных русских слов есть для того же самого. “Виноват”. Но разве можно признать себя виноватым? “Простите”. Да наплевать мне, прощаете вы меня или нет. А я сам “извиняюсь” и будет с вас. Ужаснейшее слово и ужаснейшее с ним поведение: прежде вам наступали на ногу и говорили: “Простите”, а теперь вам говорят “Извиняюсь” – и наступают вам на ногу…»

«Извините», «извините» и еще раз «извините» – только это можно считать извинением настоящим. «Извиняюсь» – в лучшем случае отговорка. А о худшем, извините, лучше не задумываться.

Comment: Справка понравилась, допустим. А что считать Ответом?

Comment: Не знаю, кем там что считается, но слово *извиняюсь* фиксируется в русском тексте уже в 1748 году.

Answer (score 2):

**Вина** из словаря Учебника Церковно-славянского языка Т.Л. Мироновой — (1) причина, источник и (2) провинность.

Если воспринимать «извинить» как «перестать считать источником, исключить из числа возможных причин», то «**извиниться**» будет равно «**не считать себя источником или причиной**» случившегося и готовности об этом говорить. То есть, человек извиняющийся не прощения просит, а уверенно заявляет о своей непричастности.

Поэтому, если насквозь пройти угрожает рассеянный со смартфоном и у него есть претензии, то «извиняюсь» и сочувствие на лице будет ему в ответ достаточным. Однако, очевидно человек причастен к событию, когда «не ответил никому до сих пор», когда «наступил вам на ногу», — извиняйся или нет, нога — у кого надо нога. О прощении умолять надо.

Answer (score 1):

"Извиняюсь" есть лишь утверждение происходящего процесса. Играюсь, катаюсь, стреляюсь. И никак к примеру "извинять себя" не подходит!

В русской литературе много примеров "извиняюсь".

"Опять тысячу раз извиняюсь, что сбиваюсь с прямой дороги в сторону", - писал Гончаров. "Извиняюсь, что не ответил никому до сих пор", - в "Дневнике писателя" Достоевского.

Извиняюсь - то же самое, что приношу извинения, то есть не прямое обращение.

Answer (score 1):

Советский писатель и переводчик Борис Тимофеев-Еропкин в книге «Правильно ли мы говорим?» писал, что сказать «извиняюсь» после неудачного поступка по отношению к другому человеку — это значит совершить ещё одну грубость, всё равно что заявить: «Я, конечно, виноват, однако не нуждаюсь в вашем прощении». Фактически смысл этого выражения: «Я сам извиняю себя за причинённое вам зло».

Языковед Афанасий Матвеевич Селищев в книге «Язык революционной эпохи» отмечал, что форма «извиняюсь» часто встречается в произведениях русских классиков: Чехова, Гончарова, Достоевского. Но, по мнению Селищева, отличие от теперешнего «извиняюсь» заключается в том, что «извиняюсь» в речи писателей находится в сочетании с другими словами в предложении и имеет обычное реальное значение - значение выражения извинения, искреннего, иногда глубокого раскаяния, что подчёркивается словами «1000 раз» и т. п.

Со времени войны 1914 года в России слово «извиняюсь» стало широко употребляться как всего лишь формальный знак вежливости. Распространению этого, как пишет языковед, много содействовали лица из Польши и с юго-запада. Такое употребление формы «извиняюсь» вызвано воздействием польского przepraszam (1 л. ед. глагола przeprositf, przepraszac — «просить прощение»).

[Источник](http://www.spb.aif.ru/culture/event/1460264)

Comment: А в 1748 оно употреблялось не как "всего лишь формальный знак вежливости"?

Answer (score 1):

Советский писатель, переводчик Борис Тимофеев-Еропкин в книге «Правильно ли мы говорим?» писал: «…сказать «извиняюсь» после неудачного поступка по отношению к другому человеку - это значит совершить ещё одну грубость, всё равно что заявить: «Я, конечно, виноват, однако не нуждаюсь в вашем прощении». Фактически смысл этого выражения: «Я сам извиняю себя за причинённое вам зло».

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что слово "извиняюсь" несёт тот смысл, что человек признает свою вину, приносит извинения, то есть раскаивается, понимает и осознаёт свою вину. Слово "простите" означает просьбу принять извинения, отнестись милосердно к раскаявшемуся и признавшему свою вину. Говорить "извините", считаю, напротив, некорректным, несмотря на многочисленные противоположные мнения.

Попробуйте оспорить - спор ради истины!

Comment: Спорить с вами никто не собирается, формат ресурса не предусматривает. Если ваш ответ понравится, его "плюсанут", нет- "опустят". Вот весь спор.

Comment: А по сути... Ну вы считаете так, я эдак, И.И. Имяреков - еще как-то. Нетпредмета ни для спора, ни для серьезного даже обсуждения. Зря, кстати, вам марафет навели. В исходном виде было очевидно, насколько бессмысленно обсуждение...

Answer (score 0):

Считаю вполне допустимым слово, вернее фразу "Я извиняюсь за ...", тут есть сообщение, что свой проступок вы считаете виной, и в данный момент вы осознаете свою вину и приносите извинения. Вежливо, корректно. В слове "извини", есть призыв и некоторая настойчивость, на мой взгляд это менее корректная форма извинения. Извинения в русском языке имеют множество нюансов, если проступок не очень большой и обида нанесена не очень сильная - извиняюсь, прошу прощения, если более сильная - извините, простите, если значимая - раскаиваюсь, умоляю о прощении.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что сообщает по этому поводу «Словарь русского речевого этикета» . Если «извините» – это широкоупотребительная форма вежливого извинения, то извиняюсь – это просторечное слово, которое, извините, находится вообще за рамками литературной нормы. Считается, что это самое извиняюсь вошло в оборот со времен Первой мировой войны.

«Кому не известна формула большевистской вежливости – извиняюсь? » – писал не без горечи знаменитый русский языковед Селищев о языке революционной эпохи. – Сколько прекрасных русских слов есть для того же самого. «Виноват» . Но разве можно признать себя виноватым? «Простите» . Да наплевать мне, прощаете вы меня или нет. А я сам извиняюсь и будет с вас. Ужаснейшее слово и ужаснейшее с ним поведение: прежде вам наступали на ногу и говорили: «Простите» , а теперь вам говорят Извиняюсь – и наступают вам на ногу...» .

«Извините» , «извините» и еще раз «извините» – только это можно считать извинением настоящим. Извиняюсь – в лучшем случае отговорка. А о худшем, извините, лучше не задумываться.

Answer (score 0):

*Извиняюсь* — это нормально в разговоре сотрудников, например. При обсуждении текущих вопросов. Быть литературно вежливым работающим долгое время вместе, в одной компании, — это смешно и практически не встречается. Я знаю лишь одного человека, который так разговаривает.

Comment: Каких сотрудников? Вы не могли бы формулировать ответ почетче?!  Или вы полагаете, что разговорный стиль неких работников одной отдельно взятой фирмы может служить нормирующим источником общелитературного языка?