# Извиняюсь или извините: просторечие или две допустимые нормы современного языка?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Я всегда говорю ***"извините"*** и молча огорчаюсь, когда слышу ***"извиняюсь"***. В Интернете много раз **обсуждалась** эта тема, в том числе [на форуме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2798/%D0%AF-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), но уже давно.

И мнения **разные**, причем **[у филологов](https://dzen.ru/a/YAp0Wm8foWXBlGPX).** Например: *Ещё в школе многим вдолбили «непреложную истину»: мол, «сь» – это сокращение от «себя». Выходит, «извиняюсь» означает «извиняю себя», поэтому и говорить так невежливо.*

**Вдолбили?** Вероятно, да? А теперь вот "вдалбливают" другое понимание. Причем не очень убедительно. Потому что критерии оценки не совсем ясны. **Какие они,** грамматические, смысловые, коммуникативные, традиционные?

Может, в регионах по-разному говорят, в то же время есть  и **общелитературная** норма. Но в каких **источниках** надо эту норму искать.

А как **говорите вы?**

Спасибо.